# Plotting time on x-axis in NetLogo

Tags: plot, time, netlogo

I am using the Time extension in NetLogo where each tick is a minute. I have set this up using `set current-time time:anchor-to-ticks start-time 1.0 tick-"minute"`.

The running of the model works fine. I am able to perform my time step actions based on the date/day/month, etc.

I am unable to plot the current-time variable though. I would want it to be on the x-axis of the plot. If I try setting a range like this `set-plot-x-range start-time end-time` in the plot setup section, I get an error like this:

```
Runtime Error: SET-PLOT-X-RANGE expected input to be number but got the org.nlogo.extensions.time.data.types.LogoTime
```

What's the alternative to this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but I don't think there is a way to plot a formatted time on NetLogo's plots. The plots can only use numbers on their axes, and your time values are a different type of variable, a Logotime, which is more like an object than a number.

Instead, you can simply use TICKS on the X axis and label the axis as simulated time in minutes.

You can also write your results to an output file, including the value of current-time formatted as a character string, e.g., using:

```
 file-type (time:show current-time "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") 
 ...
```

and then draw plots using the file output and some other software that handles dates and times.

I'm glad to see people using the Time extension!